# Script saves .jpg image to disk but image converts to .png upon upload to 3p hosting site

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, download, drawimage

The task-at-hand is to center a .jpg image (previously uploaded to image hosting site) on a 1600 x 1600 white background, and include a link which downloads the resulting image directly to my pc. The code below accomplishes the task. Upon clicking the download link, a .jpg is downloaded to my pc with the necessary specifications. HOWEVER, when this new .jpg image is uploaded to the image hosting site, the resulting upload is a .png file. The white background disappears.

Some notes: open the image with paint and save it as a .jpeg file, and a notification states that any transparency will be lost. If I were to proceed, then the image is saved with the desired specifications and will upload to the image hosting site as a .jpg. I suspect I've created an image with transparent background (not white as desired) and when removed, the transparent canvas becomes white. Additionally, the resulting .jpg image is changed to .png regardless of the 3p host I use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<left>
<a id="myAnchor" download="image.jpg"><b><u>Download</u></b></a>
</left>

<img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc475/kmkcorp/TigsMoney1_zpst9wv6cdb.jpg" id="img" style="display:none" alt="picture"/></image>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1600" height="1600" style="border:0px;"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("img");
ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2);
ctx.canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
myAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);});
var revokeURL=function(){
requestAnimationFrame(function(){
URL.revokeObjectURL(this.href);
this.href=null;});
this.removeEventListener('click', revokeURL);};
myanchor.addEventListener('click', revokeURL);};
img.src="http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc475/kmkcorp/TigsMoney1_zpst9wv6cdb.jpg";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format the question properly so people are not having to read one massive paragraph and aim to be concise with the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `type` argument of [`canvas.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) to `"image/jpeg"`.

To fill the background of the `<canvas>` to a specific color you can use `.fillStyle` and `.fillRect()`.

Also `ctx.canvas.toBlob()` should be `canvas.toBlob()`; `myanchor.addEventListener('click', revokeURL)` should be `myAnchor.addEventListener('click', revokeURL)`; and`this` is `window` within function passed to `requestAnimationFrame`. You can remove the `href` and `download` attributes if the offer for download is expected to occur only once.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <a id="myAnchor" download="image.jpg"><b><u>Download</u></b></a>

  <img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc475/kmkcorp/TigsMoney1_zpst9wv6cdb.jpg" id="img" style="display:none" alt="picture" />
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1600" height="1600" style="border:0px;"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var img = document.getElementById("img");

      ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width / 2 - img.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - img.height / 2);
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        myAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      }, "image/jpeg");

      var revokeURL = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(this.href);
          myAnchor.removeAttribute("href");
          myAnchor.removeAttribute("download");
        });
        this.removeEventListener('click', revokeURL);
      };
      myAnchor.addEventListener('click', revokeURL);

      img.src = "http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc475/kmkcorp/TigsMoney1_zpst9wv6cdb.jpg";
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @K.Corp Have you tried the code at stacksnippets at Answer?

Comment: This works perfectly and has saved me a lot of time, many thanks! One minor question...the download link is in the bottom left of the page...how can I move it to the top left?

Comment: I enclosed the link in html heading tags and it seemed to solve the issue <h1><a>.......</a></h1> though I agree CSS would be the correct route to go. This was the last step as part of a larger project so your help is much appreciated.